# How to Loop Over a list of addresses for Longitude and Latitude (Python)

Tags: python, geocoding, geocoder

I'm trying to loop over a list of addresses that I have (Street Name, City, State, Zipcode) in order to get longitudes and latitudes

```py
    for address in addresses:
          g = geolocator.geocode(address)
          print(g.address)
          print((g.latitude, g.longitude))
          LatLong.append((g.latitude, g.longitude))
```

When I run this code I receive the long and lat for the first address in the list but then get this :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'
```

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

At least some of the geolocators in `geopy` return `None` when there are no results found, as indicated [in the documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#geopy-2-0). You must check the return value before assuming that a result was returned.

Comment: Thank you. Reading through the documentation now

Comment: When I manually enter addresses that the Geocoder couldn't find during the loop they are located. Any hope of translating that back into the loop?  The underlying addresses are all formatted the same

Comment: @ynnad Are you sure that you're using the same Geocoder? If you run it through the loop again, does it still fail? Is it possible that there is some small (even invisible) difference between the two strings, such as non-printable characters?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `g` is `None` before trying to use it:

```
for address in addresses:
  g = geolocator.geocode(address)

  if g is None:
    print ('{} could not be geocoded'.format(address))
  else:
    print(g.address)
    print((g.latitude, g.longitude))
    LatLong.append((g.latitude, g.longitude))
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for the majority of the addresses. However, the rest did have g = none. (New coder here and I'm not understanding the logic as to why. Where g = none, address are present so why is g = none?)

Comment: @ynnad, `g` is none because the geocoder could not locate the address. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932658/2089675)